# umask is being ignored on Gentoo while creating new files

Tags: linux, file-permissions, drupal, gentoo, umask

I have a server running Gentoo and hosting a drupal installation.
Whenever a Drupal update is executed, the directory permissions of the updated module turn from **755** to **744** preventing the application from accessing the files.
The umask is defined as 022 under /etc/profile and the Apache server is running under user and group *nobody*.

I believe this has nothing to do with the drupal installation since if I create a directory as **root**, the same happens, it is created with 744 permissions, since the *umask* is 022 shouldn't it be created as 755 ?

Why is the **umask being ignored** and how do I tell the server to create the directories with permission 755 ?

Comment: Are you updating drupal through drupal itself?

Comment: From drupal itself.

Comment: What version of Drupal? 7.x? Have you tried, just for fun, to `grep -ir "chmod" /path/to/your/drupal`?

Comment: Yes, it's 7.x, never tried that command since I don't believe this is an issue with drupal, but will try it (just for fun :).

Comment: Are there any filesystem ACLs in place on the directory where youre creating the subdirectories? (`getfacl` to check)

Comment: No ACLs present on the system.

Comment: Do you run mod_umask or PHP through suPhp or similiar? these modules are setting the umask.

Comment: Yes! @Johann that's what I have been missing ! `suphp.conf` sets  `umask=0033`. I will gladly accept an answer !

Comment: This doesnt explain how when youre in the shell as root with a umask of 022, files are created as if umask were 033...

Comment: I agree @Patrick , must be some other parameter override elsewhere, .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my answer to your question: check the configuration of the running Apache modules (specifically mod-umask and suphp) for umask settings.